# Most user profile pages seem to be failing; activity tab unaffected

Tags: bug, profile-page

I can not currently visit user *profile* pages on any site I've tested. *Activity* pages work just fine.

[image: Profile tab circled on a userpage]

Visiting anyone else's profile link fails<sup>†</sup> since links default to the profile tab unless you're looking at your own page or you're on a site you moderate but if you force the page URL to the activity tab, you can visit their activity page with no issue, so it's only the profile part of the page that's broken. For example:

Shog9's default link (this should time out):
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9

[image: Image of user page load attempt failure with "Oops! Something Bad Happened! text]

Shog9's activity tab link (this should work):
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=topactivity

---

This is currently happening again, same time of day, same day of the week, so I'm guessing there's something running that's causing the profile pages to not populate.

So, something running on Sunday between 4:00 and 5:00  Zulu time.

---

<sup>†: Oddly, *some* user pages work just fine... so it's not *all* of them. Found a few staff profile pages that loaded just fine but some non-staff pages also work.</sup>

Comment: This seems to be fixed at the moment but based on conversation in the Tavern, it may be intermittent.

Comment: works for me ...

Comment: Maybe something poisoned the database, either mistake, or hacking attempt... if mistake doubt the team will spend much time looking into it, as it's very rare as far as I can tell.

Comment: Still leaves the question: Why are you stalking Shog9?

Comment: It was super-slow for me ~15 hours ago but eventually loaded (no error page like you got).  Activity worked fine at the time.

Comment: Not necessarily activity, but rather any tab. As long as there is `?tab=[tab]` after the link, it works.

Comment: But clicking between the tabs doesn't work@WELZ ... can you post a profile tab that does work? The generic link to one's own profile doesn't have that and it works just fine.

Comment: uhhhh, any. [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=answers), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=questions), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=answers). (btw, clicking works for me)

Comment: Right... but the *profile* tab is what I'm specifically talking about. @WELZ None of those are the profile page.

Comment: Yep, bug exists [status-YESrepro] (:P)  was just saying that the other tabs all [work as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcbOD.gif). (if you add in that line after the link)

Comment: [profile tab works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/354333/joe-friend) ([2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/6212/jason-punyon))

Comment: But those are all part of the main Activity tab. They're sub-tabs.